# iOS TableView constraints not aligned

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I put in four UITableViews into four view controllers exactly the same way and I did

> Add missing constraints from Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues

However my first table view seems shifted upwards.
I have attached the two table views.

Do anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: looking at the screenshots, the difference in heights is closer/equal to statusBar height.

I can't just figure out what it is exactly but you can look, what constraints are applied by Xcode, in the Utility Area > Size Inspector. Check for the difference in the height constraints

Comment: Don't use "Add missing constraints". you might not get what you want. Add the constraints you want explicitly.

Comment: what does your story board look like?  Have you manually compared the constraints that were set for each of the 4 views?

Comment: Check this https://www.dropbox.com/s/phfymh6kqm0j8w1/Test.zip?dl=0 I just created a demo project with 4 tableView's and all of them work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this step:

1>Remove all `constraints` of `UITableview`

2>Set your `UITableview` position (x,20,x,x)**OR**(y=20)

3>add `constraints` and Add missing `constraints` from Editor -> "Resolve Auto Layout Issues"
but remember `UITableview` top `constraint` is 0 from `Top Layout Guide`(not super view or `self.view`)

Comment: Finally understand what you were talking about, thanks a lot!! I need to get more familiar with iOS programming!!